# control volume only for opera gx with ahk

Tags: autohotkey, opera, volume

i am new here and new with ahk.

I would like to have a script to control the volume of a spereate program like in the Microsoft Sound Mixer.
I want to control the volume of Opera GX browser when it is minimized.
After some research, I found a code in the ahk forum, which works with spotify. But I need it for the Opera GX Browser

```
    If (!A_IsAdmin)
{
    MsgBox Run the Script as Administrator!
    ExitApp
}

Process Exist, Spotify.exe
ProcessId := ErrorLevel
If (!ProcessId)
{
    MsgBox Spotify is not running!
    ExitApp
}

LCTRL & UP::SetAppVolume(ProcessId, GetAppVolume(ProcessId) + 5)
LCTRL & DOWN::SetAppVolume(ProcessId, GetAppVolume(ProcessId) - 5)
Return

GetAppVolume(PID)
{
    Local MasterVolume := ""

    IMMDeviceEnumerator := ComObjCreate("{BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E}", "{A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6}")
    DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(IMMDeviceEnumerator+0)+4*A_PtrSize), "UPtr", IMMDeviceEnumerator, "UInt", 0, "UInt", 1, "UPtrP", IMMDevice, "UInt")
    ObjRelease(IMMDeviceEnumerator)

    VarSetCapacity(GUID, 16)
    DllCall("Ole32.dll\CLSIDFromString", "Str", "{77AA99A0-1BD6-484F-8BC7-2C654C9A9B6F}", "UPtr", &GUID)
    DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(IMMDevice+0)+3*A_PtrSize), "UPtr", IMMDevice, "UPtr", &GUID, "UInt", 23, "UPtr", 0, "UPtrP", IAudioSessionManager2, "UInt")
    ObjRelease(IMMDevice)

    DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(IAudioSessionManager2+0)+5*A_PtrSize), "UPtr", IAudioSessionManager2, "UPtrP", IAudioSessionEnumerator, "UInt")
    ObjRelease(IAudioSessionManager2)

    DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(IAudioSessionEnumerator+0)+3*A_PtrSize), "UPtr", IAudioSessionEnumerator, "UIntP", SessionCount, "UInt")
    Loop % SessionCount
    {
        DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(IAudioSessionEnumerator+0)+4*A_PtrSize), "UPtr", IAudioSessionEnumerator, "Int", A_Index-1, "UPtrP", IAudioSessionControl, "UInt")
        IAudioSessionControl2 := ComObjQuery(IAudioSessionControl, "{BFB7FF88-7239-4FC9-8FA2-07C950BE9C6D}")
        ObjRelease(IAudioSessionControl)

        DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(IAudioSessionControl2+0)+14*A_PtrSize), "UPtr", IAudioSessionControl2, "UIntP", currentProcessId, "UInt")
        If (PID == currentProcessId)
        {
            ISimpleAudioVolume := ComObjQuery(IAudioSessionControl2, "{87CE5498-68D6-44E5-9215-6DA47EF883D8}")
            DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(ISimpleAudioVolume+0)+4*A_PtrSize), "UPtr", ISimpleAudioVolume, "FloatP", MasterVolume, "UInt")
            ObjRelease(ISimpleAudioVolume)
        }
        ObjRelease(IAudioSessionControl2)
    }
    ObjRelease(IAudioSessionEnumerator)

    Return Round(MasterVolume * 100)
}

SetAppVolume(PID, MasterVolume)    ; WIN_V+
{
    MasterVolume := MasterVolume > 100 ? 100 : MasterVolume < 0 ? 0 : MasterVolume

    IMMDeviceEnumerator := ComObjCreate("{BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E}", "{A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6}")
    DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(IMMDeviceEnumerator+0)+4*A_PtrSize), "UPtr", IMMDeviceEnumerator, "UInt", 0, "UInt", 1, "UPtrP", IMMDevice, "UInt")
    ObjRelease(IMMDeviceEnumerator)

    VarSetCapacity(GUID, 16)
    DllCall("Ole32.dll\CLSIDFromString", "Str", "{77AA99A0-1BD6-484F-8BC7-2C654C9A9B6F}", "UPtr", &GUID)
    DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(IMMDevice+0)+3*A_PtrSize), "UPtr", IMMDevice, "UPtr", &GUID, "UInt", 23, "UPtr", 0, "UPtrP", IAudioSessionManager2, "UInt")
    ObjRelease(IMMDevice)

    DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(IAudioSessionManager2+0)+5*A_PtrSize), "UPtr", IAudioSessionManager2, "UPtrP", IAudioSessionEnumerator, "UInt")
    ObjRelease(IAudioSessionManager2)

    DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(IAudioSessionEnumerator+0)+3*A_PtrSize), "UPtr", IAudioSessionEnumerator, "UIntP", SessionCount, "UInt")
    Loop % SessionCount
    {
        DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(IAudioSessionEnumerator+0)+4*A_PtrSize), "UPtr", IAudioSessionEnumerator, "Int", A_Index-1, "UPtrP", IAudioSessionControl, "UInt")
        IAudioSessionControl2 := ComObjQuery(IAudioSessionControl, "{BFB7FF88-7239-4FC9-8FA2-07C950BE9C6D}")
        ObjRelease(IAudioSessionControl)

        DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(IAudioSessionControl2+0)+14*A_PtrSize), "UPtr", IAudioSessionControl2, "UIntP", currentProcessId, "UInt")
        If (PID == currentProcessId)
        {
            ISimpleAudioVolume := ComObjQuery(IAudioSessionControl2, "{87CE5498-68D6-44E5-9215-6DA47EF883D8}")
            DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(ISimpleAudioVolume+0)+3*A_PtrSize), "UPtr", ISimpleAudioVolume, "Float", MasterVolume/100.0, "UPtr", 0, "UInt")
            ObjRelease(ISimpleAudioVolume)
        }
        ObjRelease(IAudioSessionControl2)
    }
    ObjRelease(IAudioSessionEnumerator)
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the 7th line to Process Exist, Opera.exe

Comment: good Idea! 
Unfortunately it does not work...

Comment: Strange, as the rest of the code is windows object calls, which should be similar on that scenario. Check the name of the Opera GX executable, maybe they have changed it. 

I am currently using Mac OS X, so I won't be able to test your code, but I could suggest to remove everything except SetAppVolume(PID, MasterVolume) function and try to launch it while using a PID of the process from Task Manager.